# I am getting on error when run "meteor run ios"

Tags: meteor

I am getting an error when run "meteor run ios"

```
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.2.1, but it should have a minimum version of 4.0.0 to ensure compatibility with the current
         platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.
```

Is there any update cordova.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix this issue using following steps-:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5

meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@1.4.1

rm -rf .meteor/local/cordova-build

 meteor run ios
```

Source-: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7828