# How to adjust dependencies for Meteor/Ionic App to point dependency to Cordova version 4.0.0

Tags: meteor, cordova-plugins

I am creating a Meteor/Angular/Ionic App (`meteor create MyApp`), and when running (`meteor run ios`), a WARNING is thrown which suggests that Cordova plugin splashscreen should be updated from `3.2.1` to `4.0.0` :

> " WARNING: Attempting to install plugin
>   cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.2.1, but it should have a minimum
>   version of 4.0.0 to ensure compatibility with the current platform
>   versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you
>   should adjust your dependencies. "

I understand there are [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217054/i-am-getting-on-error-when-run-meteor-run-ios) to reinstall the cordova plugin using (which I have done but the warning still remains):

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@1.4.1
rm -rf .meteor/local/cordova-build
```

I checked my app project directory and realised that (prior to any updates), I already have Cordova 4.0.0 package installed in `../.meteor/local/cordova-build/plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "Cordova Splashscreen Plugin",
  "cordova": {
    "id": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "amazon-fireos",
      "ubuntu",
      "ios",
      "blackberry10",
      "wp8",
      "windows8",
      "windows",
      "tizen"
    ]
  },
```

So my current guess is Meteor has a config file somewhere that is NOT pointing to the Cordova splashscreen version 4.0.0 that exists.

Can any experts help me with my question:

1. Is my guess that I should modify a Config file to point to the right
   Cordova version correct?
2. Where can I find this file in my Meteor App folder?

Comment: Did you search for "3.2.1"?

Comment: Yup couldn't find. :(